# How to solve NameError:Options is not defined in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium

How to solve `NameError:Options is not defined` in AWS Lambda ?

**my attempts**

- Added selenium module file in awslambda
- aws docuemnt refer. but not solve
- stackoverflow errormessage search but not solve.

Then, it worked, but the error occurred (**cloudwatch**).

```
2021-06-28T12:30:31.892+09:00   START RequestId: 7bb8408e-2b12-4e16-80be-e6f1b0166a60 Version: $LATEST

2021-06-28T12:30:31.892+09:00   Error in Imports

2021-06-28T12:30:31.895+09:00   [ERROR] NameError: name 'Options' is not defined Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 203, in lambda_handler     instance_ = WebDriver()   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 25, in __init__     self.options = Options()
```

`selenium sample code`

```
   import json
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  
 def __init__(self):
        self.options = Options()

        self.options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
        self.options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        self.options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
        self.options.add_argument('--single-process')
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    def get(self):
        driver = Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', options=self.options)
        return driver
```

**my goals**

> Through aws_lambda, I want to collect data through crawling all day long.

Comment: Faced similar import problem once, can you please try Options.Options(), it worked for my package, not sure will work it here also, but can give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue so perhaps it can help you:

Check if the selenium, chromdriver $ headless-chromium are zipped properly.

so when you upload it as a layer to aws lambda, it has the right pathname for you to import selenium in your lambda code.

you can download the file chrome_headless.zip from: https://github.com/soumilshah1995/Selenium-on-AWS-Lambda-Python3.7

and then zip it again inside that folder, on your local machine:

```
zip -r chrome_headless.zip chromedriver headless-chromium python
```

then try to upload it to aws lambda layers, attach it to your function and test it.

**all credit goes to Soumil Nitin Shah** with his great tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWqbYiHudt8